# How to disable non-ssl connection on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache2

I am using Apache 2.2 on 12.04. I have activated **ssl** connection with a self-signed certificate which works fine, but now I'd like to disable any **non-ssl** connection.

I used  `a2dissite` default but the server is still accessible on port `80` even after restarting the server.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 14):

I finally have it working:

In addition to disabling the default page with:  `a2dissite default`, I edited `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and commented the following lines:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  
Listen 80
```

Comment: I had a snap application listening on port 80. This solution stopped apache from listening on port 80 so that requests could go through to the app.

Answer (score 12):

A better idea is to keep "non-ssl connection" (http), but permanently redirected to your SSL Virtual Host (https). In this case the `.conf` file could look like:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        # Redirect Requests to SSL
        Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.example.com/"
            
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                
                ServerName www.example.com
                ServerAdmin admin@example.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.example.com

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                # other configuration directives...
        
        </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Related topics:

- [Changing default index page with .htaccess](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901418/changing-default-index-page-with-htaccess)

Comment: May you elaborate why is a better idea to not disable HTTP? I'm investigating pros and cons of disabling port 80.

Comment: @MarcoMarsala, in most cases, when HTTP (port 80) is disabled and you are type in the browser `http://your.domain.com` (or just `your.domain.com`) you will receive "page not found" - unless you type `https://your.domain.com` ...