# How to disable non-SSL on Apache on only the host without disabling in virtual hosts?

Tags: apache2, ssl

This is an extension (not a dupe) of [How to disable non-ssl connection on Apache 2.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184791/how-to-disable-non-ssl-connection-on-apache-2-2)

Like the above question, I have:

Added a virtual host config /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf with an SSL cert.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost example.com:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /my/certs/mydomain.com.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /my/certs/mydomain.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile    /my/certs/myprovider.ca

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>


    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Then:

1. Run `a2enconf ssl` to enable SSL.
2. Run `a2ensite example.com` to
   enable my domain.
3. Run `a2dissite 000-default` to disable the host
   default site.
4. Run `a2dissite default-ssl` to disable the host
   default ssl site.

What should remain is only the site https://example.com/

However, I can also access http://example.com/ (non-SSL) which is an unexpected *feature*.

The other question's answers are to simply disable port 80 by commenting out `Listen 80` but that means that other virtual hosts won't be able to specify port 80.

Why does Apache2 appear to accept port 80 when no virtual host specifies it and what is the correct way without disabling port 80 altogether?

Comment: If your Apache listens on port 80, it will be accessible on port 80 by any name which resolves to your server's IP address. If you want to block access for a specific name, create a virtual host which directs to an error page.

Comment: It's not so much the name, but the fact that it responds on the host's IP and whatever name that matches to.  (The reverse name, for example.)  Maybe there's a setting that says not to respond to IP-only requests.  I'll look into that.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: *"Maybe there's a setting that says not to respond to IP-only requests."* No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost an answer in that it doesn't leak information out of port 80 by accident:

Create a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/forbidipaccess.conf with contents:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location />
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run:
    `sudo a2ensite forbidipaccess` and
    `sudo service apache2 reload`

This doesn't block the IP as such, but it does issue a `403 Forbidden` response if there isn't a config with that specific domain name as its ServerName or ServerAlias.

If we wanted to be super-nice and didn't like the "Forbidden" message, we could alternatively use an Apache Rewrite to return a 301/2/3 which would forward the user to the equivalent SSL, e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R=301,L]
```