# Changing default index page with .htaccess

Tags: server, apache2, php

Suppose my domain is `foo.com`, I have `index.html` in my root directory.
Then if I install a shopping cart in `/cart` and it has `index.php` as its index page.

**How would I change the default index to `/cart/index.php` using `.htaccess`?**

Comment: Monkeybus, does any of these solutions meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to make `first.html` your index page

```
DirectoryIndex first.html
```

You can also have multiple files as in :

```
DirectoryIndex first.html index.htm index.html index.php
```

Here the server will check for files from left to right and use the first one available

So I guess you configuration should be

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Since you want ot give more priority to `index.php` when it is found in a directory

Comment: Yes, but the index page I want to be default is in a different directory to .htaccess

Comment: place your .htaccess in the root directory of your website, it that does not work than place a copy of .htaccess in that folder too

Answer (score 1):

**Use Redirections:**

You can use [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive (Mod_Alias). Edit your `.htaccess` file and add this line:

```
Redirect permanent "/index.html" "/cart/index.php"
```

Or you can use [`RedirectPermanent`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) directive. Edit your `.htaccess` file and add this line:

```
RedirectPermanent "/index.html" "/cart/index.php"
```

---

**Use Rewrite engine:**

You can use [Mod_Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve the same result as the above. Edit your `.htaccess` file and add these lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !cart
RewriteRule "^$" "/cart/index.php$1" [R=301,L]
```

Further reading about Mod_Rewrite: [[1]](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules); [[2]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04); [[3]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite).

---

**Smart redirection, using PHP:**

Edit your `.htaccess` file and add these lines:

```
# Obliterate previous DirectoryIndex order:
DirectoryIndex disabled

# Create new DirectoryIndex order:
DirectoryIndex site-condition.php index.php index.html
```

Create PHP file, called `site-condition.php`, which will redirect the initial request to the first existing file according to this order priority:

1. `/cart/index.php`
2. `/index.php`
3. `/index.html`

The content of `site-condition.php` could looks like:

```
<?php
        $primary_index = 'cart/index.php';
        $secondary_index = 'index.php';
        $tertiary_index = 'index.html';

        if (file_exists($primary_index)) {
                header("Location: /$primary_index");
                exit;
        } elseif (file_exists($secondary_index)) {
                header("Location: /$secondary_index");
                exit;
        } elseif (file_exists($tertiary_index)) {
                header("Location: /$tertiary_index");
                exit;
        } else {
                echo "<html><head><title>Under construction!</title></head>";
                echo "<body><h1>Under construction!</h1></body></html>";
                exit;
        }
?>
```

<sup>According to this example `/cart` must be a sub directory of [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) of the current VHost.</sup>

Further reading about used PHP functions: [[1]](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php); [[2]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php); [[3]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).