# How to resolve a request on /folder to a separate documentroot on Apache 2.4 and pass php to two fpm pools

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

I have one domain like `http://example.com`. This results in a page loaded from `/var/www/example`. Now I want all requests to `http://example.com/site2` to be resolved to the folder `/var/www/site2`.

This is the basic idea and I tried to accomplish it like this (which did not work):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    DirectoryIndex /index.html index.html

    #<LocationMatch "^/site2.*">
    #    RewriteEngine on
    #    RewriteRule . /example2/index.html [L]
    #</LocationMatch>

    AliasMatch "/site2(.*)" "/var/www/site2$1"
    <Directory /var/www/site2>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried using the `Alias` directive and `LocationMatch` to rewrite stuff to the correct URL when arriving at the `/site2` URL. This was my conf. At `http://example.com/site2/` it would result in the `index.html` from `http://example.com/`. Only when requesting `http://example.com/site2/index.html`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    DirectoryIndex /index.html index.html

    Alias "/site2" "/var/www/site2"
    <Directory /var/www/site2>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would also like to have all PHP requests passed to their own FPM pool. The requests for `http://example.com` should be passed to `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000` and the request for `http://example.com/site2` should go to `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I cannot understand "Question 2". What you mean requests should go to `localhost`? The `localhost` ([loopback interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it)) is accessible only from the local machine.

Comment: @pa4080 I updated my question. They should be passed to fpm on fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000 and fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001.

Comment: Hi, matglas86, I'm thinking about Question 1. Could you try to remove `/index.html` from `DirectoryIndex`. Usually you don't need path and maybe this is the reason why Apache shows only the index from the the main directory.

Comment: It worked! Thats part 1. Now figure out part 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "Question 1)":

- you should add an alias:

  ```
  Alias /site2 /var/www/site2
  <Directory /var/www/site2>
      Require all granted
      AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
  ```
- The `DirectoryIndex` directive reads the statements as 'absolute' filenames. I mean with this syntax:

  ```
  DirectoryIndex /index.html index.html
  ```

  `DirectoryIndex` will check if `index.html`, located in `DocumentRoot`=`/`, exists and will display it if yes, and will ignore next statements. So if this record (`/index.html`) is not intended it is wrong. Some [examples here](https://askubuntu.com/a/901547/566421).

Comment: I tried this with no success.

Comment: @matglas86 The directory `/var/www/site2` must be readable for `www-data` also you must restart the server.

Comment: I just added my test config and my results.

Comment: If you make mention of the DirectoryIndex correction you gave in the comment I'll give kudos'.

Comment: Hi, @matglas86, I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I'm still cannot help with Question 2.