# Website redirect for https

Tags: apache2

I have a webserver running Ubuntu 14.04. we are running a number of websites on it. one of the websites requires to be run on https. I have configured the SSL certificate and https is working properly except when someone types http, its failing to redirect. 
when I edited the www.**.com.conf in sites-enabled to add a redirect configuration, its affecting all the websites running on http, taking them to the website with https.
Someone help with how I can configure to redirect http traffic to https for just one website without affecting the other websites.

Comment: your using apache httpd, right? this should do it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798882/4770754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect people after SSL is set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031457/redirect-people-after-ssl-is-set-up) (also this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/873876/566421)  as reference).